# unzip file into same directory in linux

Tags: linux, zip, redhat, unzip

Example:

Here's list of files in "/tmp/test_dir" 
file1

```
zip -r Test_Files.zip *
```

When I unzip Test_Files.zip I'm getting the below output

Current working directory "/tmp/test_dir"

```
/tmp/test_dir/file1
```

What I'm expecting when I unzip Test_Files.zip;

```
/tmp/test_dir/Test_Files/file1
```

Can anyone help how do i get expected result as mentioned above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unzip in current directory while preserving it's file structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41804425/7975442).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unzip in current directory while preserving file structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804425/unzip-in-current-directory-while-preserving-file-structure)

Answer (score 0):

Use unzip. You can use -o to overwrite the existing files and -q to make it quiet. In doubt? Just use terminal and type in unzip (or try /usr/bin/unzip) to see helpful information.